# Action bar for android in codenameone

Tags: android-actionbar, codenameone

[image]How can I create action bar and overflow for android in codenameone designer?

I have added command in form and the command work as menu which is displayed only when menu button is clicked. I want to action bar in the title.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

`ActionBar` will only appear on the physical Android 3.x or newer device. As long as you don't change the default command behavior adding commands will be mapped to a native action bar.

Comment: Dear shai 
I have used default command and add action to new form named "SubmitFormMain" and tested on Android 4 and newer samsung mobile and tablet 
And in simulator of iphone its showing on right side of title 
but in menu for android .

Comment: OK what you want is the command not to fold. To do this you will need to use Form.addCommand() via code. And do something like myCommand.putClientProperty("android:showAsAction", "withText"); to hint to the action bar to use the text of the icon